# too many arguments to function 'FILE* popen()' in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, popen

I wrote a little test program which compiles and runs as expected when compiled with GCC:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFSZ 512

int ping_test(char *host);

int main(void) {
    if (ping_test("192.168.1.1"))
        printf("PING OK!\n");
    else
        printf("PING FAIL!\n");



}

// returns 1 if ping succeeds, 0 otherwise
int ping_test(char *host)
{
    FILE *in;
    int i = 0;
    int ok = 1;
    extern FILE *popen();
    char buff[BUFFSZ] = {0};
    char res[BUFFSZ] = {0};
    char cmd[50]={0};

    sprintf(cmd,"ping -c 1 %s",host);
    if(!(in = popen(cmd, "r"))){
            exit(1);
    }
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
            strcat(res,buff);
    }   
    pclose(in);
    printf("RESULT: %s\n",res);
    // check for string "100%"
    for (i=0;i<BUFFSZ;i++) {
        if (res[i] == '\%' && 
            res[i-1] =='0' &&
            res[i-2] =='0' &&
            res[i-3] =='1'){
            ok = 0;
        return ok;
        } else
            ok = 1;
    }
    return ok;
}
```

now I'd want to use this same function in a Qt C++ program I'm working on, so I copied the function into a private method in my class:

```
int JTFTestSuite::Ping(char *host)
{
    FILE *in;
    int i = 0;
    int ok = 1;
    extern FILE *popen();
    char buff[BUFFSZ] = {0};
    char res[BUFFSZ] = {0};
    char cmd[BUFFSZ]={0};

    sprintf(cmd,"ping -c 1 %s",host);
    if(!(in = popen(cmd, "r"))){
            exit(1);
    }
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
            strcat(res,buff);
    }
    pclose(in);
    printf("RESULT: %s\n",res);
    // check for string "100%"
    for (i=0;i<BUFFSZ;i++) {
        if (res[i] == '\%' &&
            res[i-1] =='0' &&
            res[i-2] =='0' &&
            res[i-3] =='1'){
            ok = 0;
        return ok;
        } else
            ok = 1;
    }
    return ok;
}
```

declaration in header:

```
private:
    int Ping(char *host);
```

but now, it doesn't compile, the compiler complains with:

```
error: too many arguments to function 'FILE* popen()'
     if(!(in = popen(cmd, "r"))){
                             ^
```

Why is this I'm wondering?
The includes are identical in both source files

Comment: What happens if you get rid of ``extern FILE *popen();``?

Comment: in c++ your forward declarations must be full. `extern FILE *popen();` declares `popen` as taking 0 parameters and then you call it with 2. This will be rejected. Either include the correct header or forward declare it properly

Comment: @MikeVine Thanks, if you move this comment into an answer, I'll accept it as solution!

Comment: **Include the relevant header**, don't redeclare library functions yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, you can declare a function without declaring any particular prototype, by using an empty parameter list. (You shouldn't do this. It has been deprecated for a long time. But you can.) If you want to declare a function which takes no parameters, you need to use `void` as the parameter list.

This doesn't work in C++. In C++, an empty parameter list means the function takes no arguments.

So in C,

```
FILE* popen();  // unspecified what the parameters are
FILE* f = popen(cmd, "r");   // called with two strings
```

In C++

```
FILE* popen();  // takes no arguments
FILE* f = popen(cmd, "r");   // illegal because popen takes no argument.
```

Rather than declaring `popen` (and other library functions) yourself, `#include` the correct header file. `popen` and `pclose` are in `<stdio.h>`, but you need to make sure you define the correct [feature test macro](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) before any `#include`s. (`#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` will work, for example.)